# Inserting values into a table in C#

Tags: c#, sql, relational-database

I am trying to add a user to two different tables, running from SQL Server Management Studio Express, the details add for the one session only, please could people help with an answer to how i would go about making this data last in the database after the session (I apologize for poor code, I am currently only an apprentice software engineer)

```
namespace AddingANewUser
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddNewUser(String employeeID, String firstName, String lastName, String username, String password, String managerID, String accessLevelID, String phoneNumber, String departmentID)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CitySecretHRSystemConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var updateEmployees = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                updateEmployees.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, AccessLevelID, ManagerID, DepartmentID) VALUES (@employeeID, @firstName, @lastName, @phoneNumber, @ accessLevelID, @managerID, @departmentID)";

                updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
                updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
                updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", employeeID);
                updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
                updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessLevelID",   accessLevelID);
                updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managerID", managerID);
                updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departmentID", departmentID);
            }

            using (var updateLogIn = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                updateLogIn.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LogInDetails (EmployeeID, Username, KeyWord) VALUES (@employeeID, @username, @keyWord)";

                updateLogIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", employeeID);
                updateLogIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                updateLogIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyWord", password);
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            AddNewUser(tbEmployeeID.Text, tbFirstName.Text, tbLastName.Text, tbUsername.Text, tbPassword.Text, tbManagerID.Text, tbAccessLevel.Text, tbPhoneNumber.Text, tbDeptID.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest using Entity Framework

Comment: why do you call `connection.Close` then use the connection again?

Comment: What's that? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I am very new to doing this

Comment: I call the close for my own clarity, it simply makes it easier for me to see where the connection closes

Comment: You are creating them , not saving them and again calling close even if you have tasks left. I would suggest read the docs at msdn. Here is a start point that would help you - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3btz0xwf.aspx

Comment: Thank you for all the help, the docs will prove to be of great use

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you are missing the [execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) command:

```
using (var updateEmployees = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    //...
    //... 
    updateEmployees.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //...
}
```

As other people correctly point out have this in mind:

> The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) 
>       it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called.

In simple words no need to call   `connection.Close()` as `using` will take care of it and close the connection when you are done.

Comment: @swiftie821, Glad to help, pls consider marking as correct

Comment: I definitely will when I can, need to wait a few minutes it says

Comment: @apomene what about the `connection.Close();` before 2nd using block?

Comment: I noticed that myself as well, I have removed it from the equation

Comment: great. @swiftie821 edit and remove from question as well. It looks odd :)

Comment: How do I do the upvote? (I only just started using this today)

Answer (score 3):

you have to use below menioned code

```
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.CitySecretHRSystemConnectionString))
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();

        using (var updateEmployees = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            updateEmployees.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employees (EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, PhoneNumber, AccessLevelID, ManagerID, DepartmentID) VALUES (@employeeID, @firstName, @lastName, @phoneNumber, @ accessLevelID, @managerID, @departmentID)";

            updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
            updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
            updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", employeeID);
            updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
            updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessLevel", accessLevel);
            updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@managerID", managerID);
            updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@departmentID", departmentID);
            updateEmployees.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }


        using (var updateLogIn = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            updateLogIn.CommandText = "INSERT INTO LogInDetails (EmployeeID, Username, KeyWord) VALUES (@employeeID, @username, @keyWord)";

            updateLogIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employeeID", employeeID);
            updateLogIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            updateLogIn.Parameters.AddWithValue("@keyWord", password);
            updateLogIn.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

you have already implemeted `using` block so no need to close the connection

Comment: I think there should be `ExecuteNonQuery` for `updateLogIn` as well.

Answer (score -1):

You have written `@phoneNumber, @ accessLevelID, @managerID,` : No space between `@` and `accessLevel`. Also, once you call `accessLevel` and other time `accessLevelID`, I think accessLevel doesn't have ID ...

Comment: The accessLevelID is what came as part of a database supplied by the company I work for (I am lead to believe its for clarity), thank you

Comment: but you set the parameter as `updateEmployees.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accessLevel", accessLevel);`

Comment: It's a not null value field, the only reason it is in there is because it has to be for the database

Comment: I have no problem with that but why is it different from the name you gave to it in the insert query ?